# How can i send the 2d navigation goal to rviz by voice command using pocketsphinx(Turtle bot)

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can i send the 2d navigation goal to rviz by voice command using pocketsphinx

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66720/how-can-i-send-the-2d-navigation-goal-to-rviz-by-voice-command-using-pocketsphinx(turtle-bot)/) by [DCD](https://answers.ros.org/users/5339/dcd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-07-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is very simple demo of something like that, the code is a bit old and might need a few updates, but it is posted here: https://github.com/mikeferguson/maxwell/blob/sixdof/maxwell_navigation/nodes/goto.py

You'll notice that the goals are hard coded (the easiest way to do this is to use rostopic echo on the move_base goal topic, and click on your "goals" in rviz), basically, I have a name for each pose (was basically the center of the office). Video here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aABif3W6MY

UPDATE: As for implementing this on TurtleBot, if you have navigation (http://ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_navigation) running, you will need to fire up pocketsphinx with your dictionary of words (see the docs for the node http://ros.org/wiki/pocketsphinx) and make that goto.py script have the proper names and places.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DCD](https://answers.ros.org/users/5339/dcd/) on 2013-07-08**:
Thnx..but I am working on turtlebot..so how to implement this voice application on turtlebot

**Comment by [Gav](https://answers.ros.org/users/3961/gav/) on 2013-07-08**:
@DCD - Ferg's code publishes the standard move base simple goal, so any robot running the navigation stack should respond to it. You'll also need to be running the pocketsphinx recognizer too. https://github.com/mikeferguson/maxwell/blob/sixdof/maxwell_navigation/launch/goto.launch

**Comment by [femitof](https://answers.ros.org/users/39985/femitof/) on 2020-05-01**:
I am trying to do this..I need help please